# How to block a specific App from accessing my website

Tags: android, web, joomla, blacklist

Someone has an app (Android) that accesses my website and displays some pages.

I would've been ok with it except that the app has some errors and people using it are unable to use certain  functionalities of the site.

How can I block this specific app?

P.S. I have root access to my web server and it's dedicated. I run CentOs 7 and using Joomla for my website.

Comment: i don't think is possible, you can try to contact the developer of the app if he/she doen't pull down the app you can report the app

Comment: ok. Reporting might be my only option

Comment: yep and it takes less work for you, if you don't get much trafic from the app is not that important (i think)

Comment: you can't get all the users' ip addresses to prevent them from accessing your website.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apache logs for the user agent of that app, and then block that user agent. Hopefully the user agent will be unique so no other apps will be affected.